# Why by submitting a form with a link does not change the input text values?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with some hidden input fields. Additional I have a link, which has a reset function, by clicking on it, it sets the hidden fields a "0" as value and submits the form.

It works fine, except by output the POST array, I still see the old values. How can I change that ?

Here is the HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="http://localhost" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="filter_form">
<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="mWIbgqI6sXZTyZpaW3Z3x1QqxZpwnl0BdmJtDmRY">
<input type="hidden" id="select_finance" name="select_finance" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="filter_finance" name="filter_finance" value="60">
<div class="row " style="margin-top: 5px; display: none;" id="finance_filters">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="owl-carousel col-md-12">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="top_sub_link">
                    <a href="#" class="filter_link close_ink" style="margin: 5px 9px;"  data-href="finance" data-value="64">COPPER</a>
                </div>
            </div>               
            <div class="item">
                <div class="top_sub_link">
                    <a href="#" class="filter_link close_ink"  data-href="finance" data-value="63">WHEAT</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="top_sub_link">
                    <a href="#" class="filter_link close_ink"  data-href="finance" data-value="62">SILVER</a>
                </div>
            </div> 
            <div class="item">
                <div class="top_sub_link">
                    <a href="#" class="filter_link close_ink"  data-href="finance" data-value="61">GOLD</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="top_sub_link activemediasublink">
                    <a href="#" class="filter_link close_ink"  data-href="finance" data-value="60">GAS <i class="close_filter"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="owl-nav"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Here is the Javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".close_filter").on('click', function() {
        $('#filter_finance').val('0');
        $('#select_finance').val('0');
        $("#filter_form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Make sure your onClick method gets called. Eg. by logging to the console.
I dont see an element with class `close_filter` in your example.

Comment: Whoops! My bad. You cant really click on it, when it has no content tho ..

Comment: @SchokokuchenBäcker It's an icon.  Presumably some CSS is populating it with an image.

Comment: @Vince Carter is there any other javascript that attaches events on these anchors? I suppose if you click on "GAS" probably `input name="filter_finance"` receives 60 as value. Check if you have overlapping of events on clicking "close_filter" because it is inside anchor.

Comment: A code snippet would have been great for reader to reproduce the problem. But would have needed to remove jQuery before, or could jQuery be used in snippet on SO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element on which you're attaching the onClick event is not the whole link but a  tag inside the link. Thus, the clickable area is too small -maybe not even visible.

In your JavaScript, replace this:

```
    $(".close_filter").on('click', function() {
```

With this:

```
    $(".close_ink").on('click', function() {
```

Comment: Thank you! I have used the "top_sub_link activemediasublink" for the click event and now is working fine :)